# Convert HH:MM:SS.micro string to microseconds?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timedelta

I'm sure there must be a better way to convert a string like `00:04:11.723` to microseconds like this:

```
ms = timestring.split('.')
pt = ms[0].split(':')
sec = int(pt[0]) * 3600 + int(pt[1]) * 60 + int(pt[2])
st = sec * 1000 + int(ms[1])
```

but yet I didn't find it.

Comment: it's a very readable code, why you want change it?

Comment: Have you searched for something like "parsing time in Python"?

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 6):

This is one way using only `datetime.timedelta`:

```
from datetime import timedelta

x = '00:04:11.723'

h, m, s = map(float, x.split(':'))
res = timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s).total_seconds() * 1000

# 251723.0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from datetime import datetime

timezero = datetime.strptime('00:00:00.000', '%H:%M:%S.%f')
(datetime.strptime('00:04:11.723', '%H:%M:%S.%f') - timezero).total_seconds() * 1000
```

The basic idea is to use `strptime()` to parse your string to get a `datetime` object.  Since `datetime` objects don't have a nice method for total seconds, but `timedelta` does, we subtract another `datetime`, which results in the `timedelta` we're looking for.  Now we can take `total_seconds()`.  Multiply by 1000 and you have your answer (as a floating point number).

Comment: Where is the `%f` directive documented?

Comment: @martineau:  See the table under [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and also footnote #5.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at the docs for `time.strptime()` where it says that it uses the same directives as `strftime()` which doesn't list it.

Comment: Nice one.  This can be simplified to replace the `timezero` element with `datetime(1900,1,1)`, if there is no date involved.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not opposed to third party libraries, `pandas.Timedelta` might be useful for you:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Timedelta(timestring).total_seconds()*1000
```

This returns: `251723.0`